# How does one put on tefillin with a prosthetic?

Tags: halacha, tefilin, technology, parts-of-the-body, handicap-disabled-impair

[Assuming that prosthetic limbs are not considered part of one's body](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/16669/9682):

How would someone put on Tefillin if r"l his non-dominant arm was replaced by a prosthetic from the shoulder?

1. Would the halachos be the same as a [cast](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/52991/) or [other obstruction](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/17170/)? Or perhaps this case is worse, since in those cases the person has an arm, just that there's something in the way?
2. If the answer to #1 is that one should *not* put Tefillin on the prosthetic arm, is there any benefit to putting Tefillin on the biological arm, even though it's the person's dominant arm?
3. If the answer to #2 is that one *should* put Tefillin on the dominant arm, what if the person had *both* of his arms replaced? Is he entirely exempt from Tefillin at that point, or should he put it on one of the prosthetics?

([This answer](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/89332/) takes it for granted that one doesn't put Tefillin on a prosthetic arm, but it's unsourced.)

Comment: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/60422/759

Comment: There is a Shaagat Arieh on tefillin Shel Rosh for one who hasn't hand

Answer (score 1):

Rema in OC 27:1 rules that one who is missing his hand but has a remaining arm lays tefillin without a blessing, citing a *machlokes* between Tosafos in  Menachos (37a) and the Ohr Zarua.
Mishne Berura rules that one who is missing his left arm entirely - or even one is is missing the majority of his upper arm - is exempt from laying the *shel yad* at all, but that there are those who are stringent. He clarifies that this is specifically regarding the left arm (i.e. the weaker arm) as this is the prescribed place for tefillin; one who is missing his right arm is obligated to lay tefillin and would have to request assistance in laying the tefillin.

Comment: What about someone with a prosthetic? That was the whole question

Comment: OP' question led with the presumption that prostheses are not considered part of the body. If that's the case then there's certainly no difference between OPs case and a "classic" case of an amputee from the shoulder.

Comment: If that's your answer then say so, but note the OP had already seen that as an unsourced claim so you're not adding anything by just asserting it

Comment: As Double said, I’d prefer an answer that rejects my premise and is sourced than an answer that assumes my premise is correct but doesn’t back it up with anything.

Comment: Working on an edit.